# Approximation property of Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a normed space, let $H$ be Hilbert. Every $T:X\rightarrow H$ compact is the limit of a sequence of finite range operators.

*Context*: this is an exercise on Rudin's "Functional analysis". Is the following correct?

*My try*: $T(X)$ is separable, so I can find an orthonormal set $\{e_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with $T(X)=T(X) \cap \overline{\langle e_1, e_2,...\rangle}\subseteq \overline{\langle e_1, e_2,...\rangle}$. Calling $P_n$ the projection onto ${\langle e_1,...,e_n\rangle}$ I claim that $P_n T\rightarrow T$, and this would yield the conclusion.

So, let $\epsilon>0$, find $y_1,...,y_N$ such that $B_\epsilon (y_i)$ cover $\overline{T(B_X)}$ (these balls are all closed). Because $y_i \in \overline{\langle e_1, e_2,...\rangle}$ we have $P_n(y_i)\rightarrow_n y_i$, so that from some large enough $n$, we have $||y_i-P_n(y_i)||\leq \epsilon$, for every $i$.

Then, for $n$ large, $||x||\leq 1$ with $T(x) \in B_\epsilon(y_i)$ we get: $||P_nT(x)-Tx||\leq ||P_nTx-P_ny_i||+||P_ny_i-y_i||+||y_i-Tx||\leq 3\epsilon$, as $||P_n||=1$.

Comment: Really good!!!! Well, in the second line from below it's $T(x)$.